# What was inside Yuuko's wallet?

Tags: nichijou

Mio was carrying Yuuko's wallet in her bag for some reason (why?). Then the moment comes and Mio realizes that the wallet is not there. They go to the lost and found department. They found the wallet and we see inside of it as in the screen shot below. Yuuko's day is ruined after see that paper and the green thing inside.

What was that paper and the green substance that put Yuuko in such a bad mood?

---

Inside the wallet:

[image: Inside wallet]

Yuuko's mood for the entire day after this event:

[image: Yuuko's Mod]

(Location: Episode 12; at the beginning of the second half.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

( ͡° ʖ̯ ͡°) It's a [piece of snakeskin](https://youtu.be/zhz6smMccYo?t=66) and a receipt from a store in front of a [certain station](http://www.kyotoanimation.co.jp/nichijou/_userdata/map/tokisadame_station.html) she frequents.

The wallet is Yuuko's because she identified it by the color and unique contents (the snakeskin). The empty face is one of shock and perhaps angst because all her money is gone. The gag here is not the contents but her reaction after looking in her wallet.

In Japan, there is a superstition that goess if you put the cast-off skin of a snake into your wallet, your wallet will be able to accumulate more money. In Japan and other asian countries as well, snakes are a traditional symbol of money and wealth (amongst other things), in Japanese myth some notable ones associated with snake gods are Ugajin and Benzaiten.

Comment: Can you please explain more? Was that a similar wallet and she thought that it was hers? Or did someone else used her money and bought some snake skin? If so, why the hell would someone buy snake skin with the money inside a wallet he finds on the street, then puts it in the wallet and gives the wallet to the lost and found office? I can't understand the joke behind this.

Comment: @hkBattousai The snake skin was Yuuko's. It was in the wallet before. To clarify: When Yuuko gave her wallet to Mio to hold onto for safekeeping, it contained 3 things: receipt + snake skin + money. When Yuuko found her wallet at the lost and found, it contained only 2 things: receipt + snake skin. Evidently, the thief ignored the two useless things and opted to only take the money.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your side question about why Mio was carrying Yuuko's wallet in her bag:

Yuuko gave it to Mio to hold onto for safekeeping purposes, because Yuuko thought that she would just lose it if she held onto it herself. She mentions this in an earlier scene:

[image: Yuuko: "If I had it, I'd lose it."]